# How can I put a view on top of a glSurfaceView with a transparent background?

Tags: android, 3d, overlay, renderer, glsurfaceview

My app is composed (from back to front) of an image background, then a glSurfaceView containing a 3D object and on the top 2 buttons. I want the background of the GLSurfaceView to be transparent and see the image behind.

I've tried two solutions, but none of them is satisfying :

```
mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(mContext);
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);           
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mGLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
```

In this case, I can see the background, but the 3D object is floating on the top of all the other layouts, sometimes hiding the buttons.

```
mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(mContext);
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);           
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mGLSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
```

In that case, I can see the buttons, but the GLSurfaceView is no longer transparent and I cannot see the image background.
I've parsed all the other topics, but none of them gave me any satisfying answer.

Comment: I'm also crusading for an answer to this problem. As far as I can tell it is simply impossible on some devices. On other devices the second case does result in a transparant SurfaceView.

Comment: Strangely I don't have this problem on Android 2.3. Only on 4.*

Comment: Any help here would be sweeeeet

Comment: Try using `TextureView` which was introduced in 4.0 and has better performance.

Comment: It's not a performance issue

Comment: I am just wondering why don't you draw the background in your SurfaceView? @Gerard

Comment: You mean creating a 2D textured object in OpenGL? That is what I am doing currently, but the performance is much worse (loading texture is a pretty heavy operation performance-wise). Thanks for you help though

Answer (score 1):

```
final GLSurfaceView glView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glView);

glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
glView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
glView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

given by SO post:
[Android GLSurfaceView transparent background without setZOrderonTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762633/android-glsurfaceview-transparent-background-without-setzorderontop)
and the original blog post:
[How to set a transparent GLSurfaceView](http://andrewhague.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/how-to-set-a-transparent-glsurfaceview/)

Comment: Finally! Thank you! Spent all day Friday trying to figure this out.

Comment: Glad to have an answer for you,  TJ Biddle

Answer (score 0):

setZOrderOnTop() works, but it means that you can't place any graphics on top of this SurfaceView, which is unfortunate.